# Content not showing up in dynamic boostrap alert

Tags: jquery, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap-3, alert, insertafter

I'm trying to create a dynamic bootstrap alert.
However, the messages 'successfully saved' and 'failed' are not getting displayed.

When, I inspected and checked the html, I couldn't see the 'strong' tag iself getting added after 'a.close'.

What's wrong with the code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.alert').hide();
  $('#success').click(function(){
 $('.message').text('');
 $('.message').removeClass('alert-danger');
 $('.message').addClass('alert-success');
 $('.alert-success').find('.close').after('<strong>Success: Successfully saved!');    
 $('.alert-success').show();
  });
      
  $('#failure').click(function(){
 $('.message').text('');
 $('.message').removeClass('alert-success');
 $('.message').addClass('alert-danger');
 $('.alert-danger').find('.close').after('<strong>Failed!</strong>');
 $('.alert-danger').show();
  });
  setTimeout(function() { $(".message").fadeOut('slow'); }, 3000); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert message">
 <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="success">Success</button>
<button id="failure">Failure</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update function as below.

```
$('#success').click(function(){
    //$('.message').text('');
    $('.message').removeClass('alert-info');
    $('.message').addClass('alert-success');
    alert($('.alert-success').find('.close').html());
    $('.alert-success').find('.close').after('<strong>Success: Successfully saved!');               
    $('.alert-success').show();
  });
```

Here i have put comment on **$('.message').text('');** because this method text('') will clear a anchor tag as well.

Here you also need to remove old **class** and old **messages**.

Comment: I tried : [$('.message').find('strong').remove(); ] instead of [$('.message').text('')]..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.alert').hide();
  $('#success').click(function(){
   $('.message').removeClass('alert-danger');
   $('.message').addClass('alert-success');
   $('.alert-success').find('.close').next().remove().end().after('<strong>Success: Successfully saved!');              
   $('.alert-success').show();
});
$('#failure').click(function(){
  $('.message').removeClass('alert-success');
  $('.message').addClass('alert-danger');
  $('.alert-danger').find('.close').next().remove().end().after('<strong>Failed!</strong>');
  $('.alert-danger').show();
});
setTimeout(function() { $(".message").fadeOut('slow'); }, 3000);
});
```